# Como abrir uma Activity quando não tiver internet?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

Estou com um projeto que utiliza internet, e quando não tem internet o mesmo não sai do menu pois eu coloquei um bloqueio de acesso a outras activit quando não há internet, mas em fez de não abrir eu queria que jogasse para outra activity especifica, eu até consigo abrir uma pagina em branco aleatória mas a pagina que eu solicito para abrir não vem, preciso de ajuda

> **Codigo MENU**

```
public class TRABALHAR extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView xp4;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_trabalhar);

    if(!isOnline()){
        startActivity(new Intent(TRABALHAR.this,NOTICIAS2.class));
        finish();
    }// verifica conexao com a net


    xp4 = findViewById(R.id.xp4);
    xp4.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    xp4.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    xp4.loadUrl("https://clubcooeec1.blogspot.com/p/fazer-parte-da-equipe.html");

}
public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected(); // verifica se tem internet
}
```

**se eu tirar a linha**

> startActivity(new Intent(TRABALHAR.this,NOTICIAS2.class));

**o aplicativo apenas bloqueia o acesso a pagina, mas este não é meu objetivo**

como devo proceder neste caso ?

Comment: esse seu método isOnline não verifica conexão com a internet, apenas verifica se o usuário está com alguma rede de internet ativa(wifi, rede móvel...). Agora pra eu entender melhor, quando não há internet, você quer abrir uma outra acitivity? Pelo seu código não está abrindo? Para mim parece normal.

Comment: Tentou colocar já a parte desse webview dentro do else??

Comment: Quando eu executo o código sem o wifi ligado o mesmo abre uma tela Branca  menos a activity que eu quero, na activity que eu quero aparecerá  que o mesmo esta sem conexão, mass se tiver um codigo aplicável  que faça verificar realmente a internet  e avisar o usuário  ja ajuda .

Comment: Olá renan, tentei detalhar bem a resposta, pra mim funcionou bem, e com a Asynctask que eu coloquei tira a margem de erro pra quando um usuário tá com wifi ligado ou rede móvel, mas a internet tá oscilando ou muito baixa e não é possível carregar a url. Passa um feedback, se der certo ou errado. Abç

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz algumas alterações e testei em uma API 24, funcionou bem.

Primeiro crie uma classe extendendo de AsyncTask, como a seguir:

```
public class CarregaPagina extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    TRABALHAR trabalhar;
    String sUrl;
    int timeout;

    //construtor
    public CarregaPagina(TRABALHAR trabalhar, String sUrl, int timeout) {
        this.trabalhar = trabalhar;
        this.sUrl = sUrl;
        this.timeout = timeout;

    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
        //se tem algum conexão com a internet
        if (isOnline()) {
            //checa a conexão com a url
            try {

                URL url = new URL(sUrl);
                //abre a conexão
                URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
                //tempo de resposta
                urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
                //conecta
                urlConnection.connect();
                return true;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean b) {
        if (b) {
            WebView xp4 = trabalhar.xp4;

            //carrega webview da classe TRABALHAR
            xp4.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            xp4.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            xp4.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            xp4.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            xp4.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            xp4.loadUrl(sUrl);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(trabalhar, "Erro na conexão", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Erro na conexão
            chamaActivity();
        }

    }

    private void chamaActivity() {
        Intent i = new Intent(trabalhar, NOTICIAS2.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        trabalhar.startActivity(new Intent(trabalhar, NOTICIAS2.class));
        trabalhar.finish();
    }

    public boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) trabalhar.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected(); // verifica se tem internet
    }
}
```

Essa classe será responsável, por verificar se o usuário tá conectado à internet e se é possível carregar sua url, se não for capaz de carregar a url no webview, a sua Acitivty NOTICIAS2 será chamada.

Já na sua classe TRABALHAR, deixe apenas:

```
public class TRABALHAR extends AppCompatActivity {
    //deixe público pra poder utilizar na classe CarregaPagina;
    public WebView xp4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_trabalhar);
        xp4 = findViewById(R.id.xp4);

        //os parametros na ordem são: contexto, url, e timeout (tempo pra checar a url) em milisegundos.
        CarregaPagina carregaPagina = new CarregaPagina(this, "https://clubcooeec1.blogspot.com/p/fazer-parte-da-equipe.html", 2000);
        //executa a AsyncTask
        carregaPagina.execute();

    }
}
```

Comment: Mano ate agora deu certo, obrigado assim que liberar parar dar o premio te mando, so apartir de 7 horas  despois da postagem. Ok

Comment: @renansilvadasneves blz brother, mas deu pra entender como tá funcionando? Se ficar alguma dúvida me avisa que eu edito a resposta e detalho mais.

Comment: mano deu erro em 2 linhas

Comment: que foi estas aqui

Comment: CarregaPagina carregaPagina = new CarregaPagina(this, "https://clubcooeec1.blogspot.com/p/fazer-parte-da-equipe.html", 2000);
        //executa a AsyncTask
        carregaPagina.execute();

Comment: foi em CarregaPagina  e carregaPagina.execute   tão vermelhas

Comment: Qual erro q deu? E qual api vc ta testando?

Comment: Tou testando na  API 16, talvez seja isto, não cheguei execultar o codigo ,mas aquelas palavras  estão sublinhada em vermelho, aquelas que citei acima . Vou mandar print.